# Какой ассемблер выбрать для создания операционной системы

Tags: ассемблер, ос, fasm, nasm

Мне нужно знать, какой ассемблер выбрать для создания ОС на подобие Mike OS, и если Mike OS написан на nasm это не значит что мне на нем надо писать. Какой выбрать ассемблер FASM или NASM для ОС такого рода. Не хочу вмешивать Си. Прошу не писать что лучше "Потому что вам так нравится"

P.S. Я не очередной [Денис Попов](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2) т.к. делаю для личного интереса.

Comment: то, что вы не Попов, и так ясно, таким методом Поповым немножечко долго становиться.

Comment: ассемблер выбрать тот, который в нужный формат компилируется, чтобы сделать ISO. какой это формат - не знаю

Comment: Для написания ОС нет объективный причин использовать именно ассемблер (да и нет объективных причин писать ОС). С точки зрения практики - лучше все-таки использовать Си.

Comment: Выберите тот который знаете лучше. В вашем случае особой разницы будет не заметно.

Comment: У меня есть загрузчик который выводит Hello, world! так что с Iso проблем нет.